# wso2 Proxy Service unable to listen to JMS queue in multi tenant mode?

Tags: jms, wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-esb

I am using a proxy service to listen to a JMS queue when I create the proxy as a super-tenant I am able to listen to the queue and consume the messages, but whenever I am adding a queue as a different tenant I am not able to do so...
Is this a WSO2 bug... I am using wso2esb 4.8.1 .

Below is the axis.xml:

```
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--                  Parameters                       -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<!-- Change this to true if you want to enable hot deployment of services -->
<parameter name="hotdeployment" locked="false">true</parameter>
<!-- Change this to true if you want to enable hot update of services -->
<parameter name="hotupdate" locked="false">true</parameter>

<!-- Change this to true if you want to enable MTOM -->
<parameter name="enableMTOM" locked="false">false</parameter>
<!-- Change this to true if you want to enable SwA -->
<parameter name="enableSwA" locked="false">false</parameter>

<!-- If you want to enable file caching for attachments change this to true -->
<parameter name="cacheAttachments" locked="false">false</parameter>
<!-- Attachment file caching location relative to CARBON_HOME -->
<parameter name="attachmentDIR" locked="false">work/mtom</parameter>
<!-- Attachment file cache threshold size -->
<parameter name="sizeThreshold" locked="false">4000</parameter>

<!-- Completely disable REST handling in Axis2/Synapse if the value is true -->
<parameter name="disableREST" locked="false">false</parameter>

<!-- Sandesha2 persistance storage manager -->
<parameter name="Sandesha2StorageManager" locked="false">inmemory</parameter>

<!-- Our HTTP endpoints can handle both REST and SOAP under the following service path. In -->
<!-- case of a servlet container, if you change this you have to manually change the -->
<!-- settings of your servlet container to map this context path to proper Axis2 servlets -->
<parameter name="servicePath" locked="false">services</parameter>

<!--the directory in which .aar services are deployed inside axis2 repository-->
<parameter name="ServicesDirectory">axis2services</parameter>

<!--the directory in which modules are deployed inside axis2 repository-->
<parameter name="ModulesDirectory">axis2modules</parameter>

<!-- User agent and the server details to be used in the http communication -->
<parameter name="userAgent" locked="true">WSO2 ESB 4.8.1</parameter>
<parameter name="server" locked="true">WSO2 ESB 4.8.1</parameter>

<!-- During a fault, stacktrace can be sent with the fault message. The following flag -->
<!-- will control that behaviour -->
<parameter name="sendStacktraceDetailsWithFaults" locked="false">false</parameter>


<parameter name="DrillDownToRootCauseForFaultReason" locked="false">false</parameter>

<!-- Set the flag to true if you want to enable transport level session management -->
<parameter name="manageTransportSession" locked="false">true</parameter>

<!-- This will give out the timout of the configuration contexts, in milliseconds -->
<parameter name="ConfigContextTimeoutInterval" locked="false">30000</parameter>

<!-- Synapse Configuration file location relative to CARBON_HOME -->
<parameter name="SynapseConfig.ConfigurationFile" locked="false">repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs</parameter>
<!-- Synapse Home parameter -->
<parameter name="SynapseConfig.HomeDirectory" locked="false">.</parameter>
<!-- Resolve root used to resolve synapse references like schemas inside a WSDL -->
<parameter name="SynapseConfig.ResolveRoot" locked="false">.</parameter>
<!-- Synapse Server name parameter -->
<parameter name="SynapseConfig.ServerName" locked="false">localhost</parameter>



<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--                  Listeners                        -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<!-- This deployment interceptor will be called whenever before a module is initialized or -->
<!-- service is deployed -->
<listener class="org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor"/>


<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/robust-in-only"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>

<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--                Message Formatters                 -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<!-- Following content type to message formatter mapping can be used to implement support -->
<!-- for different message format serializations in Axis2. These message formats are -->
<!-- expected to be resolved based on the content type. -->
<messageFormatters>
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                      class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                      class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml"
                      class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="text/plain"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>

    <!--JSON Message Formatters-->
    <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonFormatter"/-->
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
    <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/-->
    <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter"/-->
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/json/badgerfish"
                      class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishMessageFormatter"/>


</messageFormatters>

<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--                Message Builders                   -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<!-- Following content type to builder mapping can be used to implement support for -->
<!-- different message formats in Axis2. These message formats are expected to be -->
<!-- resolved based on the content type. -->
<messageBuilders>
    <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml"
                    class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
    <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    class="org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
    <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                    class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/>
    <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"
                    class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>

    <!--JSON Message Builders-->
    <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                    class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder"/-->
    <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                    class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
    <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                    class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder"/-->
    <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                    class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder"/-->
    <messageBuilder contentType="application/json/badgerfish"
                    class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishOMBuilder"/>


</messageBuilders>

<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--             Transport Ins (Listeners)             -->
<!-- ================================================= -->


 <transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
    <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
    <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
</transportReceiver>

 <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
    <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
 <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
        <KeyStore>
            <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
        </KeyStore>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
        <TrustStore>
            <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
        </TrustStore>
    </parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="SSLVerifyClient">require</parameter>
        supports optional|require or defaults to none -->
</transportReceiver>

<transportReceiver name="local" class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportReceiver"/>


<!--<transportReceiver name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener"/>-->

<!--<transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener">-->
    <!-- configure any optional POP3/IMAP properties
    check com.sun.mail.pop3 and com.sun.mail.imap package documentation for more details-->
<!--</transportReceiver>-->

<!--Uncomment this and configure as appropriate for JMS transport support, after setting up your JMS environment (e.g. ActiveMQ) -->
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
    <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:61616</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
    </parameter>

    <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:61616</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>

    <parameter name="default" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:61616</parameter> 
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>
</transportReceiver>



<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--             Transport Outs (Senders)              -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>

</transportSender>

<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
        <KeyStore>
            <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
        </KeyStore>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
        <TrustStore>
            <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
        </TrustStore>
    </parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">DefaultAndLocalhost</parameter>-->
        <!--supports Strict|AllowAll|DefaultAndLocalhost or the default if none specified -->
</transportSender>

<transportSender name="local" class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender"/>

<!--Uncomment this local transport to use local transport in mediation flow-->
<!--<transportSender name="local" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.local.NonBlockingLocalTransportSender"/>-->
```

-->

```
<!--transportSender name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender"/-->





<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--             Global Engaged Modules                -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<!-- Comment this out to disable Addressing -->
<module ref="addressing"/>

<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--                Clustering                         -->
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--
 To enable clustering for this node, set the value of "enable" attribute of the "clustering"
 element to "true". The initialization of a node in the cluster is handled by the class
 corresponding to the "class" attribute of the "clustering" element. It is also responsible for
 getting this node to join the cluster.
 -->
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
            enable="true">

    <!--
       This parameter indicates whether the cluster has to be automatically initalized
       when the AxisConfiguration is built. If set to "true" the initialization will not be
       done at that stage, and some other party will have to explictly initialize the cluster.
    -->
    <parameter name="AvoidInitiation">true</parameter>

    <!--
       The membership scheme used in this setup. The only values supported at the moment are
       "multicast" and "wka"

       1. multicast - membership is automatically discovered using multicasting
       2. wka - Well-Known Address based multicasting. Membership is discovered with the help
                of one or more nodes running at a Well-Known Address. New members joining a
                cluster will first connect to a well-known node, register with the well-known node
                and get the membership list from it. When new members join, one of the well-known
                nodes will notify the others in the group. When a member leaves the cluster or
                is deemed to have left the cluster, it will be detected by the Group Membership
                Service (GMS) using a TCP ping mechanism.
    -->
    <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>

    <parameter name="domain">wso2.esb.domain</parameter>

    <!-- The multicast address to be used -->
    <!--<parameter name="mcastAddress">228.0.0.4</parameter>-->

    <!-- The multicast port to be used -->
    <parameter name="mcastPort">45564</parameter>

    <parameter name="mcastTTL">100</parameter>

    <parameter name="mcastTimeout">60</parameter>



    <parameter name="localMemberHost">xx.xx.xx.xx</parameter>


     -->
    <parameter name="localMemberPort">4000</parameter>


    <!--
    <parameter name="localMemberBindPort">4001</parameter>
    -->

    <!--
    Properties specific to this member
    -->
    <parameter name="properties">
        <property name="backendServerURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/services/"/>
        <property name="mgtConsoleURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/"/>

    <!-- Worker Setup-->
    <!--property name="subDomain" value="worker"/-->
    </parameter>

    <!--
       The list of static or well-known members. These entries will only be valid if the
       "membershipScheme" above is set to "wka"
    -->
    <members>
        <member>
            <hostName>xx.xx.xx.xx</hostName>
            <port>4000</port>
        </member>
    </members>


    <groupManagement enable="false">
        <applicationDomain name="wso2.esb.domain"
                           description="ESB group"
                           agent="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent"
                           subDomain="worker"
                           port="2222"/>
    </groupManagement>
</clustering>



<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--                    Phases                         -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<phaseOrder type="InFlow">

    <phase name="MsgInObservation">
    <handler name="TraceMessageBuilderDispatchHandler"
                 class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.TraceMessageBuilderDispatchHandler"/>
</phase>
    <phase name="Validation"/>
    <phase name="Transport">
        <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher">
            <order phase="Transport"/>
        </handler>
        <handler name="CarbonContextConfigurator"
                 class="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.handler.CarbonContextConfigurator"/>
        <handler name="RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler"
                 class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler"/>
        <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher">
            <order phase="Transport"/>
        </handler>

       <handler name="CacheMessageBuilderDispatchandler"
                 class="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.handler.CacheMessageBuilderDispatchandler"/>
    </phase>
    <phase name="Addressing">
        <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
            <order phase="Addressing"/>
        </handler>
    </phase>
    <phase name="Security"/>
    <phase name="PreDispatch">
        <!--Uncomment following handler to enable logging in ESB log UI-->
        <!--<handler name="TenantDomainSetter"-->
                 <!--class="org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.handler.TenantDomainSetter"/>-->
    </phase>
    <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
        <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>

        <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="MultitenantDispatcher"
                 class="org.wso2.carbon.tenant.dispatcher.MultitenantDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="SynapseDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="SynapseMustUnderstandHandler"
                 class="org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMustUnderstandHandler"/>
    </phase>
    <!--  System pre defined phases       -->
    <phase name="RMPhase"/>
    <phase name="OpPhase"/>
    <phase name="AuthPhase"/>
    <phase name="MUPhase"/>
    <!-- After Postdispatch phase module author or or service author can add any phase he want -->
    <phase name="OperationInPhase"/>
</phaseOrder>

<phaseOrder type="OutFlow">
    <!-- Handlers related to unified-endpoint component are added to the UEPPhase -->
    <phase name="UEPPhase" />
    <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
    <phase name="RMPhase"/>
    <phase name="MUPhase"/>
    <phase name="OpPhase"/>
    <phase name="OperationOutPhase"/>
    <!--system predefined phase-->
    <!--these phase will run irrespective of the service-->
    <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
    <phase name="PTSecurityOutPhase">
    <handler name="RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler"
                 class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler"/>
</phase>
    <phase name="PTCacheOutPhase">
         <handler name="CacheMessageBuilderDispatchandler"
                 class="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.handler.CacheMessageBuilderDispatchandler"/>
    </phase>
    <phase name="MessageOut"/>
    <phase name="Security"/>


    <phase name="MsgOutObservation"/>
</phaseOrder>

<phaseOrder type="InFaultFlow">

    <phase name="MsgInObservation"/>
    <phase name="Validation"/>
    <phase name="Transport">
        <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher">
            <order phase="Transport"/>
        </handler>
        <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher">
            <order phase="Transport"/>
        </handler>
    </phase>
    <phase name="Addressing">
        <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
            <order phase="Addressing"/>
        </handler>
    </phase>
    <phase name="Security"/>
    <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
    <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
        <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
        <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>

        <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
    </phase>
    <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
    <phase name="RMPhase"/>
    <phase name="OpPhase"/>
    <phase name="MUPhase"/>
    <phase name="OperationInFaultPhase"/>
</phaseOrder>

<phaseOrder type="OutFaultFlow">
    <!-- Handlers related to unified-endpoint component are added to the UEPPhase -->
    <phase name="UEPPhase" />
    <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
    <phase name="RMPhase"/>
    <!-- Must Understand Header processing phase -->
    <phase name="MUPhase"/>
    <phase name="OperationOutFaultPhase"/>
    <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
    <phase name="MessageOut"/>
    <phase name="Security"/>
<phase name="Transport"/>

    <phase name="MsgOutObservation"/>
</phaseOrder>
```

Comment: Can you post your configs?

Comment: Do you only want to check axis.xml file or any other file also...?
Below is the axis.xml config

Comment: Well, do not see axis2 config in fact. And it would be nice if you post your proxies too.

Comment: Added it in the question itself...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ChildCustomerToSnipp" transports="jms" statistics="disable"       trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
<log level="full" separator="**Consumed from IN MQ before Seq**"/>
<sequence key="ConvertCustomerSoapToJSONSeq"/>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
<sequence key="UpdateNetsuiteWithSnippMemeber"/>
</outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">Teacher.Q</parameter>
</proxy>

Comment: Do you get this error reported in this bug? https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1657 If so this is a known issue which will be fixed in ESB 4.9.0

Comment: @Ushani  Do you know when will the 4.9.0 version will be out.
I saw the Beta version has been out, where can I download it from?

Comment: Yes it is released and you can download from https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/ESB/packs/4.9.0-BETA